# How to get all childs of the parent container in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am creating dynamic containers in extjs. I have parent container whose itemId is "ParentContainer" and child container whose itemid is "ChildContainer". Now I am adding child container inside parent container by using the following code.

```
var child = Ext.createWidget('childcontainer');
var parent = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ParentContainer')[0];
parent.add(child);
```

Now its working fine but the issue is when I am trying to retrieve all the childs of the parent container by using the following code, it only returns first child but I need all of the childs

```
var par = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ParentContainer')[0];
var childs = par.query('#ChildContainer');
```

I need an array of all the childs, can anybody help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The hash tag at `#ChildContainer` tells us that you are getting the component by id. The id has to be unique across your site, so it's natural that only one component is returned.

Presumably you wanted to get all children by xtype (widget alias):

```
var childs = par.query('childcontainer');
```

Please note that this does not only give you all children of that container, but also grandchildren and so on (of the appropriate xtype).

If you only want to get direct children, your query should be

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ParentContainer>childcontainer')
```

This gets you all `childcontainer` widgets that are direct descendants of your container with ID `ParentContainer`.

If you want to get all direct descendants (children), regardless of xtype, the `par.items` property contains a list of all children of the container `par`.

Comment: Hash tag at #ChildContainer can also be used to get by itemId which maynot be unique unlike "Id"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but **parent.query()** is not retrieving all children when the child components have same "itemId". But the **Ext.ComponentQuery.query()** does retrieve all.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var containerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            itemId: 'parentPanel',
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            title: 'Container Panel',
            layout: 'column'
        });

        containerPanel.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'childPanel',
            title: 'Child Panel 1',
            height: 100,
            columnWidth: 0.5
        });
        containerPanel.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'childPanel',
            title: 'Child Panel 2',
            height: 100,
            columnWidth: 0.5
        });
        var parent = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#parentPanel")[0];
        alert(parent.title);
        //using parent.query() retrieves only one child panel
        var childsArray1 = parent.query("#childPanel");
        alert("childs1 length ->" + childsArray1.length); //length is 1

        //using Ext.ComponentQuery.query() retrieves both child panels
        var childsArray2 = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#childPanel');
        alert("childsArray2 length ->" + childsArray2.length); //length is 2
    }
});
```